# manipulate string data tabel content

Tags: c#, datatable, .net-3.5

I have a data table where some columns have comma separated strings with no space between words and the comma between them (abc,def). Can you show me how I can add a space after each comma (abc, def), short of looping through each row (Linq?)? Columns could have one or no strings at all.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: foreach (datarow dr in dt.rows) dr["some_column"] = dr["some_column"].ToString().Replace(",", ", "); I thought there should be a cleaner, Linq-like statement to do the same instead of looping.

Comment: Not sure why this off topic. It is about C#, data table column manipulation and (possibly) Linq.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public static void Main()
{
            var table = new DataTable("MyTable");
            table.Columns.Add("Col1", typeof(string));
            table.Rows.Add("abc,def");
            table.Rows.Add("ghi,jkl");

            Parallel.ForEach(table.AsEnumerable(), (row => row.SetField("Col1", row.Field<string>("Col1").Replace(",", ", "))));    
}
```

For .NET 3.5 you can apply to List ForEach implementation:

```
new List<DataRow>(table.AsEnumerable()).ForEach(row => row.SetField("Col1", row.Field<string>("Col1").Replace(",", ", ")));
```

or what is more better, define extension method:

```
public static class IEnumerableExtensions
{
    public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Action<T> action)
    {
        foreach (var item in source)
            action(item);            
    }
}
```

and then:

```
table.AsEnumerable().ForEach(row => row.SetField("Col1", row.Field<string>("Col1").Replace(",", ", ")));
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am using .Net 3.5; I believe System.Threading.Tasks is 4.5.

Comment: See updated answer for .Net 3.5

Answer (score -1):

You can run a `SqlCommand` containing an update statement such as:

```
UPDATE table SET column = REPLACE(column, ',', ', ');
```